# kernel communication

Tags: kernel-extension

I want to send a array of data to kernel space , ( i have used call back function in my kext)
problem is when i use send function i see something weird that i explain in 2 scenario:
1)
...
char f[]={'1','2','3','4','5','6'};
send (sock,f,sizeof(f),0);
well, when i printf what i receive in kext: 
123456

2)
...
// i replace f[2] with 0

char f[]={'1','2',**0**,'4','5','6'};
send (sock,f,sizeof(f),0);

but this time, when i printf what i receive in kext:
120000

it seems that send function make zero every byte after first 0 byte?
what is going on? is this a send function bug?
i used xcode 4.1 and i my os is lion
here is user space part:

```
int main(int argc, char* const*argv)
{
    struct ctl_info ctl_info;
    struct sockaddr_ctl sc;
    char str[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int sock = socket(PF_SYSTEM, SOCK_DGRAM, SYSPROTO_CONTROL);
    if (sock < 0)
        return -1;
    bzero(&ctl_info, sizeof(struct ctl_info));
    strcpy(ctl_info.ctl_name, "pana.ifmonitor.nke.foo");
    if (ioctl(sock, CTLIOCGINFO, &ctl_info) == -1)
        return -1;
    bzero(&sc, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ctl));
    sc.sc_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_ctl);
    sc.sc_family = AF_SYSTEM;
    sc.ss_sysaddr = SYSPROTO_CONTROL;
    sc.sc_id = ctl_info.ctl_id;
    sc.sc_unit = 0;
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sc, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ctl)))
        return -1;


     unsigned char data_send[]={'a','l','i','0','1','2','4','l','i',0,'1','2','4','l','i','0','1'};


    size_t data_recive;
    int j=0;
    char data_rcv[8192];


        send( sock, data_send, 17*sizeof(char), 10 );


        printf("\n");
        sleep(1);


        close(sock);
        return 0;

    }
```

and this is some part of kernel space code that is responsible for getting user space data:

```
errno_t EPHandleWrite(kern_ctl_ref ctlref, unsigned int unit, void *userdata,mbuf_t m, int flags)
{

    printf("\n EPHandleWrite called---------------------- \n");
    //char data_rec[50];

    //unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*)mbuf_data(m);
    //char ch;
    //mbuf_copydata(m, 0, 50, data_rec);

    //strncpy(&ch, ptr, 1 );


    size_t data_lenght;
    data_lenght = mbuf_pkthdr_len(m);

    char data_receive[data_lenght];
    strncpy( data_receive, ( char * ) mbuf_data(m) , data_lenght );

    printf("data recied %lu\n",data_lenght);

    for(int i=0;i<data_lenght;++i)
    {
        printf("%X ",data_receive[i]);
    }
 return 0
}
```

well, it  print in console:
61 6C 69 30 31 32 34 6C 69 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
and when i change send data to:
`{'a','l','i','0','1','2','4','l','i',**'0'**,'1','2','4','l','i','0','1'};`
i get correct, in fact i get all 0 after first zero byte in send data

Comment: I notice you're using the integer `0`, not the character `'0'` to initialise the array member. How exactly are you printing the received buffer?

Comment: when i receive n byte i iterate on them and printf them one by one like this: suppose i receive n byte                                for( int i=0;i<n;++i )                                       printf("%X",f[i]);

Comment: is it possible send and recv function set zero characters after 0 to zero??? how can i investigate this??

Comment: I think you'll need to post some actual code, it's impossible to tell what you're trying to do and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: I'am trying to code a firewall; in fact i have two program: one is kext that load in kernel and suppose to send input data to user space while other program waiting for incoming data and after some changes it reinject manipulated data to kernel space;but problem occur when i send data that contain 0 in it, recv function doesn't get data completely, and what i receive some data that after first 0 all byte are zero, as i have showed  above: i have supposed to receive 120456 but i get 120000????

Comment: You still haven't updated the post with actual code you've used on both ends.

Comment: hey dear pmjordan: i don't know how to add my code, may i email my code to you??

Comment: Click the "edit" link below the question, paste in the code and otherwise update your question. To ensure that the code gets formatted correctly, select the code and click the "{ }" button. You might need to create a proper stackoverflow account to edit, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `strncpy` line - if you look at the documentation for `strncpy`, you'll notice that it only copies until it reaches a 0 byte, so it's only suitable for dealing with C strings. If you need to copy arbitrary binary data, use memcpy.

Comment: i am looking for a way that kernel inform user space process of incoming or out comming packet till the process read from buffer that packet and does some process on it, i know that there is NOTIFICATION mechanism for that but it has overhead ( one notification structure per input or output packet ) is there any substitute solution???